# Does a $C^{1,1}$ function on $R^n$ have a second derivative in the some way?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, analysis

I have learned that a function of bounded variation in R has a derivative a.e. and I’ve also learned the Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym thm. To solve this problem, I think of the map:

$f: R^n\to R^n, x\mapsto (D_1f(x), x_2, ... ,x_n)$

As the map is Lip, we use R-N to get a derivative and finish the work.

However, I still have some questions. I cannot tell explicitly why the induced measure is absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure.

Second, I do wonder how much the derivative can be connected with the derivative we defined as the limit of difference quotient. As if n=1, the situation is the same of bounded variation, I do believe that there’s some connection.

Comment: A Lipschitz function on $\mathbb R^n$ is indeed (classically) differentiable a.e. ; this is called Rademacher's theorem. This can be found in Evans or in Evans&Gariepy, or I believe in Leoni (textbook authors)

Comment: @CalvinKhor I just googled the name and found it on wiki. Thank u very much for ur help.

Comment: You're welcome: I will also add that i think you are in a good position to read the proof. When I first learned the statement of Rademacher, I did not know the 1D result for BV functions (or even what BV meant) which is used in the proof

Comment: @CalvinKhor I just finished the proof Found on wiki. It used the one dimension which was proved by BV which gave me some other thought—if the worst condition we can get through is BV in1D, what would it be in nD? Is there some lemme as rising sun lemma allowing us to get the existence of derivative defined as limit of difference quotient?

Comment: Nice. Unfortunately I have no idea how to generalise it, but it is certainly interesting to think about! There is also the Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem but its not quite the same

Comment: @CalvinKhor Quite so. I’m reading a book about pde these days and it sometimes do need to consider the difference quotient type derivative. However, I don’t think I do have learned many tools about it—maybe I need to raise a new question.

Comment: The last chapter of Evans and Gariepy's book on Measure theory & fine properties of functions has a result for BV in $\mathbb R^n$, but I do not understand it (it requires splitting $Df$ into its ac part and its singular part). They also define an 'approximate derivative' and show that $f\in BV$ is approximately differentiable a.e.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I’ve never read that book. While learning real analysis my teacher strongly recommended it but those incredibly constructed theorems was kind of difficult for me to comprehend. But I do know the definition of approximately and I know that a function in $W^{1,p}$ is approximately differentiable a.e. After all, thank u for ur help again but it sounds like I gotta read this chapter to discuss it with u. Wish u good luck!